# Why my shinyApp doesn't plot anything?

Tags: shiny

I made almost everything the same what's in the course and it doesn't work. Do I need special settings

```
##
# Shiny nr 1
#

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage("Hello World!"

                ,sliderInput(inputId = "x"
                            ,label = "wybierz numer"
                            ,value = 25, min = 0, max = 100
                            )
                ,plotOutput("rys")

                )

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$rys <- renderPlot({ hist(rnorm(100)) })                                                           })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You have additional parentheses on the right of the `output$rys` outside the field of view.

Comment: unbalanced parentheses, remove the last one in `hist(rnorm(100))`

Comment: I don't understand can ya post this code with an amendment?

Comment: aaaa now I see :D jsut a mess in the code. thx